# Repeated Measures Design for Multiple Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, regression, repeated-measures

My study consists of a participant sitting at a computer and rating how much they like an image for over 150 trials, while listening to a distractor stimulus. We expect to see changes in their ratings as the distractor increases in intensity (Rating ~ Intensity), but am unsure how to code this in R as I am new to statistical programming.

Would there be any recommendations to where I should start, or books/links I could read that have a similar example?

Thank you

Comment: [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good candidate for a mixed effects regression model. The lmer package would fit a suitable model, and you would be able to explore fitting curves via polynomials or splines for the variation in effects over trial.

The lmer package is on cran, here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf

This is a review of a good book on growth curve modelling (a subset of mixed models) which would be useful here https://www.r-bloggers.com/guidebook-for-growth-curve-analysis/